# Zend Form Multicheck dynamic

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form

hi i'm using zend form multicheckbox.

I have an $array in which I have a list of 'id' 'name' 'surname' 'address' and 'city'of  a users.
I need to create a checkbox in which i can choose beetwen the name+surname+add+city and return to controler the id of the name and surname selected...

Here is my form:

```
class Application_Form_MultiplaSelezione extends Zend_Form
{
public function init()
{
    /* Form Elements & Other Definitions Here ... */
}

public function selezione($array){
    $this->setMethod('post');       
    $count=count($array);       
    $multipla=new Zend_Form_Element_MultiCheckbox('scelta');        
    for($i=0;i<$count;$i++){            
        foreach ($array[$i] as $chiave=>$valore){
            if($chiave=='idnomeutente'){
                $nomeutente=$valore;
            }
            if($chiave=='nome'){
                $nome=$valore;
            }
            if($chiave=='cognome'){
                $cognome=$valore;
            }   
            if($chiave=='indirizzo'){
                $indirizzo=$valore;
            }   
            if($chiave=='residenza'){
                $residenza=$valore;
            }   

        }
        $val=$nome.' '.$cognome.' '.$indirizzo.' '.$residenza;
        $multipla->addMultiOption($nomeutente, $val);


        if($i==0){
            $iduser=$nomeutente;
        }
    }   

    $multipla->setValue($iduser);

    $submit= new Zend_Form_Element_Submit('submit');
    $submit->setLabel('Seleziona');

    $this->addElements(array($multipla,$submit));           
}
    }
```

why doesn't it work???

Comment: Your code is unclear, what's your expected output exactly? What does `$array` contain? What do you mean by "return to controller the id of the name and surname selected"?

Comment: Also, "why it doesn't work" is a good question to ask to a soothsayer, here most of people can answer questions in reading errors first. What doesn't work?

Comment: I write that in the array there is a list of user with id name surname address and city. I want to have a multicheck element with a list of all the element, and i want to select its id. I say it does't work because if i try to see the page nothing appens and the browser continue to loading something...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try read and understand this:

```
<?php

class Application_Form_MultiplaSelezione extends Zend_Form
{
public function init()
{
    $this->setMethod('post'); 

    $multipla=new Zend_Form_Element_MultiCheckbox('scelta');
    $multipla->setMultiOptions($this->getOptionsToMultipla());

    /* some other fields */

    $this->addElements(array(
        $multipla,
        /* others fields */
        ));
}

public function getOptionsToMultipla()
{
    /* there you can use static or dinamic method which: 
        1. select data from table
        2. in foreach remake rows to your form, and add it to array ($array[] = "your string";)
        3. return $array;
        TIP: you should make other array where you have id of the rows, with it you can decode the request (compare index given from form)
        (if you have problem with it I can help you in other thread :)*/

    /* for example of static method */
    return Your_Model::getOptionsToMultipla();
}
```

To this code you must add some changes in your model and controller. Good Luck :)

Comment: I figure out what was the problem for which the browser wasn't working. But now i have a strange problem. The code to reach the info in the array (expressed in my code) don't works. It's strange because i use the same code with the same array before in the controller's action. I'm using it in the form now, i think that is the same, but in the form that code don't work....browser log is: Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()...if you think that is better i'll open another post..

Comment: try change it http://pastebin.com/YTNXQgJb for it: http://pastebin.com/3wfa7BdR if $valore.cognom give an error try change it on $valore['cognom']

Comment: i discover that the problem is another...i pass the array between action with $this->_helper->redirector('action', 'controller', NULL, array('array'=>$array)); The redirector seems that don't works well...

Comment: Try do it like I tell you In first post. Then it work correct for sure.

Comment: My problem is that i have an array in one action and i pass the same array in another action whith the redirector and it don't works...if i use your code with my array the result probably will be the same...i'm quite overtopics now probably...i don't know stackflow rules...

Comment: My method don't gives params to other action. But it isn't importand. Are you sure you get param correctly?

Comment: i know but what i do but must receive the array(before correct now incorrect) from another action...your code is perfect if the array comes from my model and that appens but in the action before...i can pass the array beetween action or pass an id and do the select in database again...i can do that but I did not want to make the same query to the database twice.

Comment: I think that take data from db again it's better, and faster solution, so maybe do this?

Comment: yes i think that probably is the best way...thanks for you help.